# Insert Interval into a disjoint set of intervals

Tags: algorithm

Given sorted disjoint sets `(p,q`) where `‘p’` is the start time and `‘q’` is the end time. You will be given one input interval. Insert it in the right place. And return the resulting sorted disjoint sets.

```
Eg: (1,4);(5,7);(8,10);(13,18)

Input interval – (3,7)
Result : (1,7);(8,10);(13,18)

Input Interval – (1,3)
Result: (1,4);(5,7);(8,10);(13,18)

Input interval – (11,12)
Result: (1,4);(5,7);(8,10);(11,12);(13,18)
```

[Inserting an interval in a sorted list of disjoint intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564598/inserting-an-interval-in-a-sorted-list-of-disjoint-intervals) , there is no efficient answer here

Comment: Do you assume your initial intervals to be sorted? If so, how?

Comment: sorted as in  , they are disjoint  , the interval which comes before in the numberline is earlier

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark , please see the examples for more clarity on question

Comment: This question has a richer discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837663/algorithm-to-deal-with-set-intervals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question and examples imply non-overlapping intervals. In this case you can just perform a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) - whether comparison is done by start time or end time does not matter for non-overlapping intervals - and insert the new interval at the position found if not already present.

*UPDATE*

I missed the merging occurring in the first example. A bad case is inserting a large interval into a long list of short intervals where the long interval overlaps many short intervals. To avoid a linear search for all intervals that have to be merged one could perform two binary searches - one from the left comparing by start time and one from the right comparing by the end time.

Now it is trivial to decide if the interval is present, must be inserted or must be merged with the intervals between the positions found by the two searches. While this is not very complex it is probably very prone to [off-by-one errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) and requires some testing.

Comment: As the first example shows, you might also have to combine intervals. Anyways, it's still a simple task if the original intervalls are sorted;)

Comment: I would add that you can just combine intervals at the insertion point if your interval is overlapping the intervals already there.